# what does this mean? "This is precisely because a library should not be deterministically recompiled for all users of the library."

Tags: rust, version-control, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and is trying to understand the Cargo thing. I read in their FAQ about ["why do binaries have Cargo.lock in version control, but not libraries?"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries) but do not understand what this means.

"Users dependent on the library will not inspect the library’s Cargo.lock (even if it exists). This is precisely because a library should not be deterministically recompiled for all users of the library.

If a library ends up being used transitively by several dependencies, it’s likely that just a single copy of the library is desired (based on semver compatibility). If Cargo used all of the dependencies' Cargo.lock files, then multiple copies of the library could be used, and perhaps even a version conflict."

Appreciate if anyone can explain this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say we have the following crates:

- `string-tools`: this is some kind of commonly used library exporting a `FastString` struct that has faster implementations of some commonly needed functions. This library has two versions: 1.0.1 and 1.0.2. Version 1.0.2 was recently released.
- `database`: a library to interface with your favorite database. It needs to do some string processing, and so it uses the `string-tools` library. One of the public methods in `database` has a signature like this:

  ```rust
  fn get_username(id: u64) -> string_tools::FastString
  ```

  The library has not had a chance or need to update to version 1.0.2 of `string-tools` - maybe it's unaffected by any of the bugs that were fixed in the patch. Consequently, it's Cargo.lock pins the version of `string-tools` to 1.0.1.
- `client`: this library is for interacting with the client. It also depends on `string-tools`, and has a method like this:

  ```rust
  fn show_name(name: string_tools::FastString)
  ```

  This library is using the most recent version of `string-tools`, version 1.0.2. That is also the version in its Cargo.lock.

You would like to write a website that makes use of the `database` and `client` libraries. When you build your project, Cargo compiles each library's dependencies with the versions that are specified in the Cargo.lock. This means that `database` uses version 1.0.1 of `string-tools` and `client` uses version 1.0.2. But now imagine that you've written some code like this:

```rust
client::show_name(database::get_username(id));
```

This *should* compile. After all, the `get_username` function returns a `string_tools::FastString`, which is accepted by the `show_name` function. But it doesn't! That's because the `FastString` returned by `get_username` comes from version 1.0.1 of `string_tools`, while `show_name` wants a `FastString` from version 1.0.2! This can't work; after all, when the patch to `string-tools` for version 1.0.2 was written, it's possible that the author added an additional field to the type. There's nothing reasonable for the compiler to do.

This kind of issue is avoided by having Cargo ignore the Cargo.lock file on libraries. Instead what it does is compile both `database` and `client` against the 1.0.2 version of `string_tools`. This is correct because 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 are "semver compatible versions." That means it is ok to change out one for the other, things must still compile. Now you no longer get a compiler error, because the types that the one function returns and the other function accepts are no longer different.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and brilliant explanation. It totally solved my question!

Comment: what if one was one 1.0.2 and another was on 2.0.0, and they aren't semver compatible?

Comment: @jeremymeadows Cargo would not be able to do what it does in this scenario, and so you'd get the compiler error I mentioned

Comment: @DreamConspiracy sorry, I meant more what would *we* do in that situation? it sounds a bit like that problems needs to be propagated to the library maintainers, and the best Cargo can do it explain what went wrong: [two different versions of a crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22750)

Comment: Yeah, there's no "immediate" way that you can fix it. Two semver incompatible versions of a library might as well be two separate libraries