# How to let a package use the same version of dependencies as B?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project A and B like the following, B depend on A. A is a git submoudle.

```
repo
|- contrib
|--- A
|----- components
|------- package A
|------- package B
|----- Cargo.toml
|- B
|--- Cargo.toml
```

A have dependency like the following

```
// A/Cargo.toml
serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_ignored = "0.1"
serde_json = "1.0"
tempfile = "3.0"
lazy_static = "1.3"
```

I want B have the same dependency version like A, like the following

```
// B/Cargo.toml

compA = { path = "../A/components/compA" }
compB = { path = "../A/components/compB" }

serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_ignored = "0.1"
serde_json = "1.0"
tempfile = "3.0"
lazy_static = "1.3"
```

However, once A is updated, it may updates its dependencies. So A may use `serde = "2.0"` later. So how can B "automaticly" update its serde to 2.0?

I think I need something that says "B depends the serde which A is depending".

Comment: This is not a good idea: if the version is updated, and the new version isn't compatible, it may break the package. The very existence of SemVer is to prevent accidental breakage.

Comment: If A use serde = 1.0 and B use serde = 2.0, since B depends A, then A and B are using different versions of serde, I think it may cause problems?

Comment: It definitely can, but only if they try to use the same types. If each uses serde for its own, that should be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import version of dependency which other dependency requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482188/import-version-of-dependency-which-other-dependency-requires)

Comment: This answer gives a short example on what Cargo tries to do behind the scenes to resolve possible dependency problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946327/what-does-this-mean-this-is-precisely-because-a-library-should-not-be-determin/71946527#71946527

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am not sure if this can answer my question, since it involve something I am not familiar with now. I'd like to take a look at those first.

Comment: Why not have A expose/reexport those crates, and B use them via those exports?

Comment: @eggyal do you mean something like `extern crate xxx`?

Comment: They mean in `A` to do `pub use serde;` etc.

Comment: But `pub extern crate` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I need something that says "B depends the serde which A is depending".

If they are part of the same Cargo workspace, then (since 1.64) you should use [workspace dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#the-dependencies-table).

Otherwise, `A` should expose/re-export the relevant crates (or parts thereof), for example:

```rust
pub use serde; // etc
```

and then `B` should use those exports rather than declaring each dependency in its `Cargo.toml`:

```rust
use A::serde; // etc
```

Comment: That is possible only if you have control over `A`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. On the other hand, given that the OP wants to automatically upgrade, maybe not.

Comment: That's not of great use if `A` doesn't do what it _should_ as @ChayimFriedman mentions. For example: `bio` crate uses `bio-types` as output but doesn't export definition of these types.

Comment: At which level should the `pub use serde;` happen? In the root `mod.rs` so that it can be exported directly as `A::serde`? Otherwise it might require extra `::` in between, right?